# How to modify the behavior of a ScrollBar?

Tags: html

I'm working on a document in HTML and I want to modify the behavior of a ScrollBar, that when you Scroll it sends you to a specific position of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to use javascript. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a javascript Library) will help you with some build in functions like [`.on('scroll')`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and [`.scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

As it is not clear from your question when to scroll where I just tried to made an easy to understand example. Listening on the window scroll position and when it reaches `3000px` from top it goes back to postion `800px` from top. If you want to try play with it. Do not forget to include jQuery! For assistance leave a comment.

```js
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  $( ".show-position" ).html($(window).scrollTop());
  
  if(3000 < $(window).scrollTop()) {
    $("html, body").scrollTop(800);
  }
  
});
```

```css
.show-position {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px; top: 10px;
}

.high-content {
  height: 100000px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.scroll-to {
  position: absolute;
  top: 800px; left: 200px;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  border: dashed 5px red;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-position">start scrolling</div>
<div class="high-content"></div>
<div class="scroll-to">I'm positioned 800px from top.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch the scroll event and update the top position but you can't modify the scroll bar directly because the element is rendered by the OS in many browsers and JavaScript doesn't have an API to talk to it - you can just say that you want scroll bars with an element and which ones (vertical, horizontal, both or none), that's it.

With CSS3, things are starting to get better but only Webkit seems to be supported: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/

See also:

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/
- https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/674478/Customize-Scrollbars-using-CSS